# geolocation not updating state reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React, what I'm trying to achieve is that when I click on a button my location gets detected and updates the state, I've tried doing this however for some reason it is not updating my state, I've searchedall over the internet but couldn't find a solution that matches my business. Your assistance is much appreciated.

```
this.state = { coordinatesList: [123, 456], [567, 891]  }

<button onClick={this.addCurrentLocation}></button>

addCurrentLocation() {
var coordinatesList = this.state.coordinatesList;
console.log("coordinatesList ", coordinatesList)
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  coordinatesList.push([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]); ==> this doesn't work
})
// coordinatesList.push([123, 456]); ===> this works
   this.setState({
     coordinatesList
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `getCurrentPosition` is async so you would have to place the `setState` inside the callback, otherwise `setState` gets called before the `getCurrentPosition` ends.

```js
addCurrentLocation() {

  var coordinatesList = this.state.coordinatesList;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    coordinatesList.push([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);

     this.setState({
       coordinatesList
     })
   }) 
}
```